# In what order is an offer letter signed?

Tags: signatures

I received an offer letter which has space at the end for the execs' signatures and below that for mine. But the execs' signatures are missing and I have been asked to return a signed copy so that the execs may sign after I have done so.

Is this usual? I would imagine that the execs should sign on the offer that is being made to me, instead of them asking me to sign first.

Comment: Why do you think the execs should sign first?

Comment: (It doesn't matter who signs first, but you should ask for a copy of the signed contract)

Comment: @GregoryCurrie, because they are the ones supposedly making the offer. How can I trust the offer letter if the execs have not signed it? And with the usual reading order of top to bottom, the place for their signature appears before mine.

Comment: @wsaleem What do you mean, how can you trust it? You read it, and if you are happy with the terms, you sign it. You shouldn't trust it any more or any less if they have signed it.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie I think OP is worried about signing to CompanyA and then giving notice to CompanyB (or turning down offers at CompanyC, etc.) only for CompanyA execs to back out despite him having already signed the contract.  So, it's probably more an issue of educating OP that "Signing first is perfectly fine, but that doesn't constitute a 'signed contract' until you have proof the execs signed - so don't quit your dayjob." or something along those lines.

Comment: @wsaleem I understand your concern but you can not trust a signed offer letter either.  Just recently Zillow did a mass layoff and this included rescinding some signed offers.  Rather than worry about order of signature, ask them for a signing bonus.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is this usual?

It happens. In practice it makes little difference. Just make sure you don't quit your existing job until you have the signed offer in hand.

Comment: and have all the required checks completed (drug screen, background check, employment verification, etc.)